# Need to fill large data field

Tags: worksheet-function, form-fill

I have downloaded some data that need sorting individually into date order, however the date only appears on a single title line per category, and is in text form. The only way I can see of doing it is to add the date to each line, I know I can copy and paste but there is about 4k lines so am looking for something that might speed the process up a bit.
I am fine with changing the text to a date, and deleting what currently occupies the field separately if required.
Have attached an example, any help would be appreciated
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYPqc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The useful thing here is that each "group" is immediately preceded by the word "Order_id". Because of that, you can use this formula in a new column to the right of the Order_id:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A3),RIGHT(OFFSET(A3,-(ROW()-MAX(IFERROR(FIND("Order_id",$A$1:A3),0)*ROW($A$1:A3))+1),0),10),"")
```

[image]

So, we're looking for the max row containing order id preceding the current row and populating the date if the current row is a number in column A.